# Implementing fast "GetCurrentThreadId" in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

Windows NT has a nice function named `GetCurrentThreadId` that does what its name implies.  Its implementation is very fast because it merely reads a variable from thread-local storage that is written there during thread creation by the NT kernel.  I'd like to implement that in Linux, but I've run into a snag.

My initial implementation was this:

```
typedef pid_t ThreadID;

ThreadID GetCurrentThreadId(void)
{
    static __thread ThreadID t_cachedID = (ThreadID) -1;

    if (__builtin_expect(t_cachedID == (ThreadID) -1, 0))
    {
        t_cachedID = (ThreadID) syscall(__NR_gettid);
    }

    return t_cachedID;
}
```

The problem is `fork`.  In programs that use `fork`, `t_cachedID` becomes stale - the new child process's main thread has a copy of the thread-local storage of the thread that called `fork`, and that `t_cachedID` is no longer correct.

The solution is supposed to be `pthread_atfork`, so as to change the `t_cachedID` value in the new child process to -1, but as is the norm for the Pthreads API, it's poorly-designed.  If you are a DLL that gets unloaded using `dlclose`, `pthread_atfork` doesn't know this, and will still try to call your function upon a `fork`, and kaboom.  Poor design decision #1.  There is no API to remove your callback function, either.  Poor design decision #2.

There is an vaguely-documented glibc function named `__register_atfork` that seems designed to handle this problem, but it takes a DLL handle instead of providing a way to remove your `*_atfork` handler.  Poor design decision #1 by glibc when trying to work around POSIX's poor design decisions.

How do I get my own DLL handle?  In Linux, it seems like `dlopen` returns a different `void *` handle for each time someone calls `dlopen` on a DLL/.so file, rather than merely maintaining a reference count...?  It's not like Windows where a DLL handle equals the base address of the section mapping.  Unless there's some easy way to get your own DLL handle in Linux, this makes poor design decision #2.

Is there a better, proper way to do this?

Comment: Because you are using a thread local static variable and for copies this, pthreads is badly designed? Also, Linux has no DLLs. It has shared objects, which tend to differ quite a lot at the lowest level...

Comment: Why don't you use the result of `pthread_self()` to uniquely identify a running thread or what `pthread_create()` sets as the identifier for the freshly created thread?

Comment: rubenvb: They're libraries and dynamically linked.  The reason that the API is badly designed is because `pthread_atfork` cannot safely be used by code that can be unloaded.  If it weren't a design problem, glibc wouldn't have created this `__register_atfork` function.  The same goes why `__cxa_atexit` was created: `atexit` has the exact same problem (i.e. POSIX doesn't learn from history).

alk: Because `pthread_create`'s return value doesn't match the value of `pthread_self` returned by the thread that was just created, and has lifetime issues.  It's not a very useful identifier.

Comment: "*pthread_create's return value doesn't match the value of pthread_self returned by the thread that was just created ...*" I strongly doubt this, to not say your statement is simply wrong (assuming your code is not). This assume we are not talking about `pthread_create()`'s **return** value (which indeed is just an error indicator) but about the value it sets to the `pthread_t` typed variable which's address is being passed into. If the latter does not match what the created thread returns by calling `pthread_self()` there obviously has to be something wrong with the code doing such calls.

Comment: "*lifetime issues*" same for any process id, and that is what the "gettid()" system call returns.

Comment: POSIX states that `pthread_t`'s are not directly comparable, and that calling `pthread_equal` is required to check for equality.  This thus makes `pthread_t` values unable to be, for example, keys in hash tables.  However, as far as Linux goes, where `pthread_t` is a pointer in NPTL, you are correct; `pthread_self` does return the same value as `pthread_create` returns in `*thread`.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm, actually posix already [contains function](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/3c/thr_self/) that returns thread id:

```
 pthread_self() //thanks to alk
```

Old answer:

```
int thr_self()
```

Comment: `thr_self` appears to be specific to SunOS and doesn't seem to exist in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The offset 0x2D0 may wrong for other distros or kernels.
You may search for it.

```
inline int GetCurrentThreadId()
{
    int result;
    asm("mov %%fs:0x2D0, %0\n\t"
        : "=r" (result));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only fast answer here. pthread_self() != gettid().